# In Minecraft, I made a tellraw command but it wouldn't show even though its almost exactly similar to another. Any ideas why this happens?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a tellraw command that is almost exactly similar to another, the command is the only difference, and I can't figure out why the command doesn't work. Any ideas why?
My tellraw command:

```
tellraw @a {"text":"Tp all?","color":"blue","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @a 0 50 0"}}
```

Any ideas why this command doesn't work, if it helps, I am using 1.12 Minecraft.
**Edit:**
my other tellraw

```
tellraw @a {"text":"Kill All players?","color":"green","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/kill @a"}}
```

Any idea why the second tellraw **appears** while the top doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the command as it was stated in the question and it functions properly in minecraft 1.12.

I recommend using a tellraw generator.  [Using this one](https://www.minecraftjson.com/) I got this command:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"Teleport All?","color":"blue","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @a 0 50 0"}}]
```

The tellraw generator allows you to enter text, desired color, and desired events and it produces a command which can be copied and pasted into minecraft.

The command it produces has square brackets [ ] that your command does not.

Comment: Does the command function properly?  That is the generator a linked to.

Comment: It functions properly for me.  I am not sure to be honest.  As I stated, so did your original command.

Comment: I mined and placed the command block, and it worked. Weird.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the parentheses by curly brackets: tellraw @a {...}

Comment: Did this solve your problem, or was there a mistake in your question?

Comment: It works fine for me when I try it. it teleports all players when clicked to 0 50 0. obviously only if the clicking player is OP.

Comment: @B.Polk Ah I see you already edited your question, originally it had parenthesis in the command instead of curly braces.

Comment: @Plagiatus, it's not that the command doesn't work, the tellraw doesn't appear on the screen, whereas my other tellraw appears and kills everyone.